# How to save data from DataSet in database

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, dataadapter

I simply want to import data from Excel workbook into dataset and save to to database. What confuses me is that I already gave the dataadapter parameters connecting it to Excel, imported data successfully (HasChanges() = True) and I have no idea what to do next - shall I open new connection to dbMain.sfd (SQL compact database with table NamesTable to get the data), make new dataadapter?

I know it's trivial, maybe after so many hours of constructing this code I'm too blurred to get it right. Any help, especially code sample, very appreciated.

```
    static void accesData()
    {

        //  1. OleDbConnection argument constructor
        string Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.;";
        string Source = @"Data Source=C:\Users\zenon\Desktop\People.xlsx;";
        string Rest = "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";

        //  2. Beginning of connection. Create OleDbConnection object with connectionstring as argument

    using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Provider+Source+Rest)) 
    {
            // a) Open connection
            connection.Open(); 

            // b) Create OleDbCommand sql query object
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE Name='John' OR Name='Maciej'", connection); 

            //  c) Create adapter object taking query object as argument - it stores data now
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command); //create adapter object


            //***Clear Dataset
            ds.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("Dataset zawiera rowsów " + ds.NamesTable.Rows.Count + ".");
            ds.NamesTable.AcceptChanges();

            //  e) Fill Table in Dataset with data from adapter. Make dataset dirty.
            adapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
            adapter.Fill(ds.NamesTable);

            //  f) Check how many (if any) rows where inserted into db

            MessageBox.Show("Dataset zawiera rowsów " + ds.NamesTable.Rows.Count + ".");

            bool zmiany = ds.HasChanges();


    // I added code to pass data from database to dataset but i get Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. Is that the way to do it?


             string Provider2 = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0.;";
            string Source2 = @"Data Source=C:\Users\zenon\Desktop\aaa     PS_C#\AccDB\AccDB\dbMain.sdf";

            using (OleDbConnection con2 = new OleDbConnection(Provider2 + Source2))
            {
            con2.Open();
            OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.Update(ds, "NamesTable");

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32581/Import-Data-from-Excel-to-SQL-Server) you can find an example where data are imported from xlsx to mdf(but it's the same thing import data to mdf or sdf. One other thing the correct string for access to excel is `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";`. Take a look here for more information [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Comment: @Tinwor than you, but I do not have problems accessing Excel or passing the data ot dataset, I'm just confused how to sent it further from ds to db. Please refer to last 10 rows of my post to check my attempt to do this ("Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" on upload line)

Comment: look at the sql statements that get executed when you call adapter.Update ... I guess you will find a "insert into [Sheet1$] ..." while [Sheet1$] is probably not be the name of a table in your sdf file